# React mutex via global variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, concurrency, mutex

We are using `React` and `Redux`
How can we protect the resource from accessing it with the help of mutex?

Is it OK to do this via global variables and where to store them?
PS we don't want to do this via Redux because of state update latency

Small example to give more context

```
export default function configureStore() {
  const store = createStore(rootReducer, persistedState, composedEnhancers);
  store.subscribe(
    // saveState saves state to localStorage
    // here we need mutex which will prevent state from saving to localStorage
    // and some way to toggle this mutex
    throttle(() => {
      saveState(store.getState());
    }, 2000),
  );
  return store;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if that's a correct solution
Keep in mind this works because `store.subscribe` listens to redux state changes

```
export default function configureStore() {
  const store = createStore(rootReducer, persistedState, composedEnhancers);
    store.subscribe(
      throttle(() => {
        const currentState = store.getState();
        // if we allowing state to sync with localStorage
        if (currentState.isMutexVariable) {
          saveState(currentState);
        }
      }, 2000),
    );
  return store;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I might not be understanding you completely. Are you trying to make the program wait for a line of code to finish executing before moving on to the next? This way, multiple "things" don't access the same resource at the same time.
You could use an async/await function to do this. For example:

```
async function f() {

  let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve("done!"), 1000)
  });

  let result = await promise; // wait till the promise resolves (*)

  alert(result); // "done!"
}

f();
```

Comment: No, we need to check if some variable is present. We don't need async/await thx. Question is more about how to do this in right way.